# How to select all the checkboxes when selecting single checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Hi

A problem occured when trying to select all check boxes on selecting single checkbox. 
These are dynamically produced (Via AJAX) check boxes so  binding event was some tedious. Following is the code in html

```
<form id="frm" name="frm">
    <input name="chk" type="checkbox" id="chk" value="" />main checkbox
    <input name="chk1" type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="" />1
    <input name="chk2" type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="" />2
    <input name="chk3" type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="" />3
    <input name="chk4" type="checkbox" id="chk4" value="" />4
    <input name="chk5" type="checkbox" id="chk5" value="" />5
    <input name="chk6" type="checkbox" id="chk6" value="" />6
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$(this).prop('checked')`, you can just use `this.checked`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").on("click", "#chk" , function() {      
        var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
        checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#chk').change(function () {
        $('#frm input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sd5By/)

Comment: yes fiddle will work if "chk" loaded at the time of DOM content loaded , if "chk" loaded in DOM by AJAX request .change wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#chk", function () {
        var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
        checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

this will work if click on "chk" checkbox it will check all checkboxes within that form, 
even they are loaded via Ajax